# How do sefardim pronounce the tzerei follow by a yod?

Tags: sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, pronunciation, vowels-nekudot

The tzerei makes an "eh" sound according to most sefardim.

Does the same hold true when a yod follows the tzerei?

An example is elokehnu or elokeynu in "shema yisrael".

I am a interested to know this in order to read the Jewish prayers more properly.

Comment: The Yod is not pronunced, the tsere only remain.

Comment: @Loewian
See a [good reference (ot vav)](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=6915&st=&pgnum=18&hilite=)
כתב הרב משה קמחי בספר המהלך שאחרי כל ת"ג נח נסתר ואחרי כל ת"ק נח נראה  ע"כ והדברים ברורים לפי שכל תנועה גדולה היא נמשכת בנשימה עד שתנוח אחריה אחת מאותיות או"י שהיא בכוח שמך התנועה גדולה ההיא

Comment: It was addressed to you!